# Which basic C library functions can I implement to practice and improve my skills in C?

Tags: c, libc

I know it sounds kind of subjective, but I want to implement basic library functions in C in order to gain better understanding in C (mostly in pointers) and improve my skills, since I'm only a beginner (in C & programming in general).

I also find it useful since you get to understand better what happens behind the scenes and how those basic functions work.

Which basic C library functions can I implement? I'm looking for simple ones like `strcpy`, `atoi`, `strstr` that are not too complicated (I'm only a beginner) but still require some thinking.

Comment: collect the KnR'c epic book on C and go through the exercises.

Comment: Just pick one, read the a manual/reference page until you are confident you understand what it does, then just implement it. Make lots of tests which compares the result with the actual function. When you got one right, continue on to the next function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But which functions should I look for? I only know about String functions, are there any other basic ones that I can implement? perhaps functions related to memory management?

Comment: Try to write a replacement for getopt(). That will need al your string handling and pointer / indexing skills. Extra bonus points if you use a struct somewhere. Double bonus for using function pointers. Triple bonus for varargs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings function are always challanging (and required). Try split a string to tokens, join strings, replace string in strings. Believe me, after that not only you will be a better C programmer, you will also appreciate open source libraries! (and C++ STL..)
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After having implemented `strtok()`, you may want to switch to next level with `qsort()` and its function pointer.